# ""a" and "b" depict the y-coordinate of each end point respectively of the curved line."

Tags: singular-vs-plural, mathematics

[image]

I am writing something about cubic interpolation.

An end point is a 2d point with coordinates (x,y). A curved line only has two end points, the starting point and the ending point.

Which of these sentences should I use:

1. "a" and "b" represent the y-coordinate of each end point respectively of the curved line.
2. "a" and "b" represent the y-coordinates of the end points of the curved line.
3. "a" and "b" represent the y-coordinate of the end points of the curved line.
4. "a" and "b" are the y-coordinate of the starting and ending point respectively of the curved line

Where "a" and "b" are any two terms (numbers), "a" should be for the starting point and "b" should be for the ending point.

is there a better way to write it ?

Comment: I don't know what "a" and "b" are mean to be.  There's no "a" or "b" in the picture.  I'm quite sure that "depict" is the wrong verb to use. It means "represent in a painting" or "describe in words"  How do you "depict" a coordinate (which is a single number).  Do you mean the numbers/variables "a" and "b" **are** the y-coordinates....

Comment: I changed it to "represent", but I worry about the rest of the sentence

Comment: Yes, "a" and "b" are numbers, actually they are f(0) and f(1) but I don't think that is important

Comment: The only real question present is "Is there a better way to write it?" It would help us if you could tell a little more about what you think might be a problem with the current version.

Comment: Your labels, "endpoint" are connected to points in 2-d space, not just to the y-coodinates. If you want them to represent what you said, the labels should connect to positions on the y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of your choices, I would select #2:

> "a" and "b" represent the y-coordinates of the end points of the curved line.

Because *"a" and "b"* is am plural expression, the singular "coordinate": should not be used.

One might also write:

> - "a" and "b" are, respectively, the y-coordinates of the starting and ending points of the curved line.
> - "a" is the y-coordinate of the starting point of the curved line, and "b" is the  y-coordinate of the ending point.
> - "a" and "b" are the y-coordinates of the end points of the curved line.
> - "a" and "b" are the values of the y-coordinates of the end points of the curved line.

I would avoid "represent" and say either that a given variable **is** the y-coordinate or that it is the **value of** the y-coordinate. When the two variables are refereed to together,  "coordinates" should be used, not "coordinate".

Comment: Even “value of the *y*-coordinate” sounds redundant to me since the *y*-coordinate *is* a value.